# Filter on CassandraJoinRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have applied a join on file and existing Cassandra table via joinWithCassandraTable. Now, I want to apply a filter on joinCassandraRDD. Here is the code and functionality which I have written for extraction of data:

```scala
var outrdd = sc.textFile("/usr/local/spark/bin/select_element/src/main/scala/file_small.txt")
  .map(_.toString).map(Tuple1(_))
  .joinWithCassandraTable(settings.keyspace, settings.table)
  .select("id", "listofitems")
```

Here "/usr/local/spark/bin/select_element/src/main/scala/file_small.txt" is the text file which is having a list of ids. Now, I have some elements in another list, say userlistofitems=["jas", "yuk"], I need to search 'userlistofitems' sublist from 'listofitems' column of joinCassandraRDD.

We have around 2Million ids where we have several user_lists for which we have to extract the data from Cassandra. We are using versions spark=2.4.4, scala=2.11.12, and spark-cassandra-connector=spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.2-3-gda70746.jar.

Any help is highly appreciated.

References Used:
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsenTP029tM

Comment: Any leads @alex?

Comment: why not to try SCC 2.5?

Comment: Yes, we can do but in that case, we have to upgrade and require management approvals before that, then we can upgrade the version, however, could you please suggest the ways here... Appreciate your kind help and support.

Comment: I can't say anything right now, need to look. maybe tomorrow.

Comment: Sure, thank you so much for looking into this query... I will wait for your response.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not completely understand what do you want to achieve - do you want first join on the IDs and then search inside the `listofitems` column based on the data from `userlistofitems` ?

Comment: @AlexOtt, Here:
1. We have source ids in the file (file_small.txt) which we are joining with table to find the `listofitems` (the column holds the <list> datatype having some unique Ids.)
2. Once we fetch this RDD (source ids, CassandraRow(source ids, List<Unique Ids>)), we need to filter user-provided unique Ids which are stored in list `userlistofitems`.
Here, we have the source ids column indexed only, hence, I am trying to fetch associated unique ids (`listofitems`) based on that. Since, this table is 1TB, hence I was thinking of not filtering user-provided unique Ids directly.

Comment: @AlexOtt, Please let me know in case it is unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Any leads @AlexOtt ?

Comment: Any leads anyone on this requirement? Actually, I am kinda stuck with this. Thinking what can be offered by spark-cassandra-connector...

Comment: Spark Cassandra Connector will do just the efficient join, but then search in the list items will be done by Spark itself.

Comment: ok @AlexOtt, I will try this and update here after successful implementation. Thank you.

Comment: also, look into the execution plan for the final RDD. Add `.toDebugString` to the RDD that implements the search in sublist